# Install Python package from monorepo

Tags: python, git, pip, monorepo, python-poetry

We have a private git monorepo which hosts a number of Python packages. Poetry was the dependency management tool initially chosen for the project. Anyway, due to [this Poetry issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/2242), it would not be accepted solution that involves creating new `setup.py` files.

A simplified version of the structure:

```
git-monorepo
├── pkg-1
│   ├── pkg
│   │   └── mod1.py
│   └── pyproject.toml
├── pkg-2
│   ├── pkg
│   │   └── mod2.py
│   └── pyproject.toml
└── lib
    ├── pkg
    │   └── lib.py
    └── pyproject.toml
```

The library distribution package `lib` is indepentent from any other package. However, `pkg-1` depends on `lib` and `pkg-2` depends on both `pkg-1` and `lib`.

So, the question is:

**How would be the proper way to use `pip` to install a package from this monorepo?**

Let us consider as an example that we try to install `pkg-1`, where `pkg-1/pyproject.toml` includes the following lines:

```
...

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
lib = {path = "../lib/"}

...
```

The result from running `pip`, as explained in the [VCS support documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support):

```sh
$ pip install -e git+https://gitlab.com/my-account/git-monorepo#"egg=pkg-1&subdirectory=pkg-1"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hblanco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3101, in __init__
    super(Requirement, self).__init__(requirement_string)
  File "/home/hblanco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 115, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement("Invalid URL: {0}".format(req.url))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid URL: ../lib
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the above setup is that the dependency is specified as a path dependency. When installing it, it uses that path dependency.
I ran into the same issue with a python monorepo, where I wanted to share the packages also to other projects.
I found 2 approaches to work for me:

1. in the CI/CD build pipeline, edit the `pyproject.toml` just before creating the wheel (which is published to a pypi repo)
2. First create the wheel (or `.tar.gz`) artifact, and then modify it afterwards (by extracting it, replacing the path dependencies, and zipping it again).

The full approach I've explained [here](https://medium.com/@gerben-oostra/python-poetry-mono-repo-without-limitations-dd63b47dc6b8).

However, it won't work with the `git+https://..`.
You'll need a (private) pypi repo somewhere. Gitlab provides one for each project, which I utilize in the demo project [here](https://gitlab.com/gerbenoostra/poetry-monorepo/)